# Hover both items

Tags: css

I have a list, UL, and i want next thing: when I hover the one element of list change color of span and backward.

HTML

```
<ul class="cf">
            <li>One<a href="#" class="class">Olympia</a></li>
            <li>Two<a href="#">Salem</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="bull class"></a>
```

And CSS

```
  #div ul li{
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:20px;
 }

 #div ul li a{
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: 400;
   margin-left:10px;
 }

  #div a.bull{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

I think: hover first apply to second and backward.. Any can give me a hint ?

Comment: As far as hints go, look into using the `+` operator in CSS selectors: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: The color of what span?

Comment: When i hove a li element change color of <a href="#" class="bull class"></a> and backward

Comment: As quantumwannabe suggested, use `li:hover a { ..styles here.. }`

Comment: @ZachSaucier, I edited my answer because the OP doesn't want the child anchors changed, they want the outer anchor which is a sibling to the `ul` (and therefore uncle to the `li`s) changed

Comment: @user3671971 Please show the actual markup you have.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with CSS, as there is no parent selector. However, it is quite easy to do with Javascript:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        document.querySelector('.bull.class').style['background-color'] = 'blue';
    });

    lis[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        document.querySelector('.bull.class').style['background-color'] = 'red';
    });
}
```

What this does is bind to each `li` element's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, and changes the `background-color` properties of the `bull class` anchor when the events fire.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbm3f5eb/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for suggest but the problem is, i have a bull for each li

Comment: You might suggest how to do it with plain javascript as well, given it's quite simple to do and doesn't require a massive library like jQuery

Comment: @user3671971, Can you show what your HTML looks like with multiple bulls?

Comment: yes, so` the deal is next: I have a list with a few li. after that in the end of the page I have a few links with bull stylized. When hover li change color of bull and when i hover bull change color of li, but in same time.

Comment: @user3671971 Please post some markup. It is very difficult to help without being able to see how your page is structured.

Comment: it`s a prototype it`s just this structure, above

Answer (score 0):

try this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qevwLsco/10/) see if that is what you want

html:

```
<ul class="cf">
        <li>One
            <a href="" class="class"> Olympia</a>
        </li>
        <li>Two<a href=""> Salem</a></li>
</ul>
```

css :

```
ul li a:hover{
color:pink;
}
ul li a {
color:green;
}
```